# How to make the commerce_kickstart distribution fully multilingual?

Tags: i18n-l10n, search, commerce

I just downloaded and installed the [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) 7.x-2.0-rc1 distribution.

Now I'm in the process of making it fully multilingual. I have no problem with the products.

But I don't know how the make multilingual the Search blocks (Facet) which you can see in the left sidebar in [this demo](http://demo.commerceguys.com/ck/products). I already enable the taxonomy_translation module, then I'm able to translate the terms used by the facet. But if I switch languages the facet shows all terms regardless the language the term is in. I also enabled the [facetapi_i18n](http://drupal.org/project/facetapi_i18n) but I see no changes at all.

Any suggestions about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at these two different resources:

[Configure entity translation for Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/node/1818938)

and

[Search API Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_et)